# What is AutoFixture AutoMoq?

Tags: moq, autofixture

I was looking at nuget and wanted to import moq when I noticed AutoFixture AutoMoq. I see that AutoFixture is to help write TDD faster but I can't find any examples of AutoMoq and how it is different then AutoFixture.

Can someone point me to this AutoMoq so I can see what it is doing.

Comment: Example: http://nikosbaxevanis.com/2011/02/22/creating-test-fixtures-easily-with-autofixture/

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In short, AutoFixture.AutoMoq is an extension that turns [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture) into an [Auto-Mocking Container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container/) using the [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) dynamic mock library.

There's also a similar extension for AutoFixture that enables auto-mocking with [Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx).

This article introduces auto-mocking for AutoFixture: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/19/AutoFixtureAsAnAutomockingContainer.aspx.

Here's a couple of follow-ups:

- http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/25/ChangingTheBehaviorOfAutoFixtureAutomockingWithMoq.aspx
- http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/11/13/RhinoMocksbasedAutomockingWithAutoFixture.aspx

Comment: Hmm I am still not getting how to use autofixture moq.

Comment: @chobo2: What are you trying to do?

Comment: It would be good to see those links in the AutoFixture documentation.

Comment: also: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container/
also: I'm pretty sure that MarkSeemann is the "ploeh", the author of AutoFixture :)